# setup gitolite on mounted device - ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, mount, gitolite

I'm a first-time-user of Linux, using Ubuntu 14.04

I installed gitolite on /git (which is home directory for user 'git-repo') and there is a mounted directory /git/repositories (I tried to mount both network drive(CIFS), and hard disk drive(FAT32). Of course all the permissions on mounted /git/repositories for user 'git-repo' is granted)

However, when I try to setup, (with public key of admin user 'gitolite') it fails with an fatal error:

```
$ ./gitolite/src/gitolite setup -pk ./.ssh/gitolite.pub
Initialized empty Git repository in /git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/
FATAL: could not symlink /git/.gitolite/hooks/common/update to gitolite-admin.git/hooks
 at /git/gitolite/src/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Store.pm line 372.
```

I tried without mounting drive, It successed.
What is that FATAL error talking about, what is the problem, what is the difference between mounted directory and normal directory???

Comment: FAT32 doesn't support symlinks, but this program wants to use them. You'll have to use a different filesystem.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm trying to enable read/store repositories in windows server. So what filesystem sould I use? is there any filesystem which can used in both windows and linux and supports symlink?

Comment: @이예찬 what version of gitolite are you using?

Comment: @VonC I'm using v3, the newest ver. from https://github.com/sitaramc/glitolite